# Black space all round Website

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a portfolio and I've been tinkering with the CSS on the home page. I've cleaned up my CSS but somehow i have a giant gap and the bottom and a small gap at the top of my home page(the black spaces).i think it may have something to do with the background-size being set to contain. but i don't want to change it because the image stretches out too much(i like where it is now).

Here is my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#background {
  background-image:url("images/Untitled-1.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;    
}

header{
  background: rgb(115, 78, 116);
}

p{
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-top: 15%;

}

body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer{
  color: antiquewhite;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


h1{font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  color: floralwhite;
  font-size: 300%;

}

nav {
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 40%;

}
.stretch{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(40, 31, 17);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  /*    standard syntax*/
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  /*    standard syntax*/
  transition-property: transform;
}
/* tabs will extend to left slightly*/
.stretch:hover { -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  /*    standard syntax*/
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: antiquewhite;   
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Tavyon Richardson</h1>
    <ul class="icon">
      <li><span class="list">TavyonRichardson@yahoo.com</span><i class="material-icons">mail_outline</i></li>
      <li><span class="list">989-285-5133</span><i class="material-icons">call</i></li>
      <li><span class="list">Alma, Michigan</span><i class="material-icons">location_on</i></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div id="background">
    <p><span>Hey!</span>Welcome to my webiste. Here, you can see everything from my life story, to my my recent projects and resume.</p>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="stretch"><a href="">About me</a></li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="">Courses</a></li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="http://tavyonrichardson.com/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="http://tavyonrichardson.com/nms_114/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="stretch"><a href="">Resume</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using to view your website?

Comment: google chrome for right now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see the background so not sure, but i think the problems is the margin

- Add `margin-top:0` to your `h1` on `header`
- Remove (or change value) the `margin-bottom` attribute of the `nav`

Comment: im not sure why it's not showing up. i'll check my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the margin on your `nav` and your `p`, just remove them and add `float` to the both items.

```
p{
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* position:absolute; You don't need this */
    /* margin-left: 50%; REMOVE THIS */
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-top: 15%;
    float: left; /* Float for positioning */
}

nav {
  float: right; /* Float for positioning */
  /* REMOVE MARGIN
    margin-left: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 40%; */
}
```

Here is a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/2chc2f0y/)

But your website has a lot more. Consider using a grid system such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to create your layout.

Comment: i wanted the <p> to be next to the nav, because my image(which for some reason is not showing) is on the left side. but i did change the nav to float:right and that fix the bottom gap.

Comment: so i fixed all the gaps but now my image isn't showing up? any ideas? does it have something to do with float?

Comment: @cale_b *floats* should be used anytime when is needed and when is used properly. In this case we have a good reason if he wants the sidebar to be at the very right side of the site.

Comment: @TavyonRichardson In your example you didn't add the image. Where do you need it?

Comment: i believe the image is in the code, but i want it below the header .

Comment: but i want the full image to be displayed, i dont want it to stretch.

Comment: i made a div with class=background to put the image in

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your CSS to remove the margin gap above the navbar

```
.stretch:first-child {
    margin: 0px;
}
```